# Where to get Debian Sarge (3.1)?

Tags: debian

The full CD ISO files seem to be gone:
https://www.debian.org/releases/sarge/debian-installer/

What would be the easier way to get Debian Sarge? Would the netinst work (would the packages still be available)?

Answer (score 2):

The packages are available, but not on the main mirrors/cdn.

A copy of most  things can be found on the archive repo.

- http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/sarge/main/

If you have a supported network card by the built in kernel, then you probably could use the mini iso.

- http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/sarge/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso